# Sometimes when I lock the screen and try to resume my work the password screen acts like something is repeatedly trying to log

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

Sometimes when I lock the screen and try to resume my work the password screen acts like something is repeatedly trying to log.
The end result is that I can't type anything and the error message when you put the wrong password keeps flickering below the input box.
At first I thought that maybe the Enter key was pressed since I was using an external keyboard but even after disconnecting it and putting it to sleep it was still the same.
Both times I had to hard reset my laptop.